# PostgreSQL: How to make a function store its last returned value?

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

I want to implement a `smooth_random` function that returns a value that differs from the previous by no more than a defined step. Is it possible to store the last returned value of the function?

Comment: No, but you can do it youself. Save that value yourself somewhere (in another table) and then use it in the next function call. And overwrite it every time.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks It work ideed. But using a table makes my script 15 times slower...

Comment: Really. I don't think it should. It's just a simple insert&select on a one-row-table. how can it get so slow? If it goes from 2ms to 30ms, than it's still fine :D

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks I am inserting 30000-1000000 values, and it goes from 5-10 secs to several minutes. And thats really feelable.)

Comment: does each one have to be a separate function call? maybe you can pass iteration count, use a loop, take prev value from db only the first time and then overwrite the value with each new-found-value in each iteration. then u have 1 db call instead of 30k. And then when loop is done, you store the last value for the next time if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to persist data in a database is a table. So you could in principle have a table with a single row that stores the value.

Things become more difficult if the function is called in several transactions concurrently, then the behavior would be undefined.

Using `UPDATE ... RETURNING` to update and retrieve the stored value from the table would serialize the access via a row lock, so one concurrent call would have to wait until the previous one is done.

Comment: There will be no concurrency. I will try it out